# get value of html table row tag using php

Tags: php, html

Table:

```
<table class="secondary">
<tr><td>BB:</td><td>112</td></tr>
<tr><td>CC:</td><td>99</td></tr>
<tr><td>DD:</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

for example I want to get third row of this table.

I know how to get values from div tag using ID, like:

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('http://www.results.com');
$thediv = $doc->getElementById('result');
echo $thediv->textContent;
```

but how can we get the values from table row tag?

Comment: It depends. If your example table is actually relevant, then the best you can do is find the tables with the class "secondary", but that require that either a) you actually want to look at all tables in the markup with that class, or b) The table you're after is the only one with that class. If neither of those are true, then you're going to have problems.

Comment: The example content does not include a `DIV`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DomXpath http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

(Assuming for this example that your table is the first table on the page with class="secondary")

For example:

```
<?php

$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("filename.html");

$xpath = new DomXpath($doc);
$row = $xpath->query('//table[@class="secondary"][1]/tr[3]')->item(0);

// Get the html of the third row:
echo $doc->saveHTML($row);

// Get the values from the td's for the third row
foreach ($row->childNodes as $td) {
    echo sprintf("nodeName: %s, nodeValue: %s<br>", $td->nodeName, $td->nodeValue);
}
```